# Counterexamples to the following statements

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

For any two functions $f_1, f_2 : [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$, define the function $g : [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ as follows $$g(x) = \max(f_1(x), f_2(x))$$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. There are three claims to this question,

1. when $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linear, then $g$ is linear.
2. when $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable then $g$ is differentiable
3. when $f_1$ and $f_2$ are convex then $g$ is convex.

I am able to prove the last statement by inequality condition of convex function but i can't think of the counterexample to first and second statement.

Could this be solved using the definition of max function

$$ max{(f(x),g(x))} = [f(x) + g(x)]/2 +\lvert [f(x) - g(x)]/2\rvert $$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the functions $f(x) = x-\frac{1}{2}$ and $g = -x+\frac{1}{2}$ on $[0,1]$.

Then their maximum $h(x) := \max(f,g) = |x-\frac{1}{2}|$ (as you can easily check. Since we get an absolute-value, this function is not differentiable at $x = \frac{1}{2}$. Now assume that h is of the form $h(x) = a \cdot x+b$
for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ (affine-linear). As such, it would have to be differentiable everywhere in $[0,1]$. Which it is not.

Note that I assumed everywhere that you meant "affine-linear" by linear. That means functions of the form $f(x) = a \cdot x+b$.
Because for purely-linear functions $f(x) = a \cdot x$ the statement should be true, not false.

Comment: thanks, i didn't realize it is that easy.

Comment: I hope this matches your definition of linear function. Something of the form $f(x) = a*x+b$. Because strictly speaking, this would be affine-linear. I have often seen the other definition in this context though.

Comment: actually that was the confusing part for me, i was considering purely-linear function. but it isn't mentioned in the question either just given that statement about g(x) being linear will not be true.
but either way you gave me another view to look at the question, i was merely fixated on what the suggested answer is telling and not considering the possibilities. 
thanks :)